# Segmentation fault while using pointer to pointer to a char

Tags: c, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

While compiling and executing the below program i am getting a warning during compilation and seg fault during execution.

Warning

```
program.c: In function main:
program.c:17: warning: passing argument 2 of convertString from incompatible pointer type
```

line 17 is the call to `convertString(input, &output);`

attaching the debugger is can see the segfault is occuring at the below line

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400521 in convertString (input=0x7fffffffd100 "abcdefg", output=0x7fffffffd0f0) at program.c:9
9           **output = *input;
(gdb) s

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void convertString(char *input, char **output)
{
    if(strlen(input)== 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    **output = *input;
    (*output)++;
    convertString(input+1,output);
}
int main()
{
    char input[] = "abcdefg";
    char output[sizeof(input)];
    convertString(input, &output);
    printf("%s", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: If you are implementing a `strcpy`, use `strlen` is not a good idea. To prevent an undefined behaviour check the lenght with a max threshold or until you find a `'\0'`. Also beacuse each recursion re-call `strlen`...

Comment: a *double pointer* is `double *`; you are using *pointer to char pointer*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `output` is not a pointer, it's an array, and using the address-of operator on an array gives you a (single) pointer to the array (in your case of type `char (*)[8]`). For clarification: `(void *) output == (void *) &output`, both the decayed pointer of the array, and the pointer to the array, are equal.

So you're not really passing a pointer to a pointer to `char` to the function.

---

Besides the above, I see no reason that the function should take a pointer to a pointer, a plain single pointer should be enough. Otherwise you will get wrong result when using `output` in the `printf` call as then `output` would point beyond the end of the string.

Also, you don't terminate the `output` string.

Comment: @Eregrith no, because the result of a cast is a temporary.

Comment: @Quentin Yeah I thought so. What should be done by OP then? (Apart from the obvious removal of 1 star on each param)

Comment: _So you're not really passing a pointer to a pointer to char to the function, but just a plain pointer to char_ - this is incorrect.

Comment: @Eregrith Well, to pass a pointer to a pointer to the `char`s, you need that second pointer to be an lvalue. So, first define it and point it at the array, then take its address.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Care to elaborate? Because using the address-of operator on an array gives you a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg An array decays to a pointer to its first element. A pointer to an array does not.

Answer (score 3):

You do not really need a double pointer to the output buffer here, a plain `char*` suffices:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void convertString(char *input, char *output)
{
    if(!(*output = *input)) // Copy the zero terminator as well.
        return;
    convertString(input + 1, output + 1);
}

int main()
{
    char input[] = "abcdefg";
    char output[sizeof(input)];
    convertString(input, output);
    printf("%s", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Character array `output` has type `char [sizeof( "abcdefg" ) ]` that is equivalent to `char[8]`. So expression `&output` in function call

```
convertString(input, &output);
```

has type `char ( * )[8]` while the corresponding parameter of the function has type `char **`. They are incompatible types and the compiler points to this mistake.

There is no sense to declare this parameter as having type `char **`. It has to be declared like `char *`.

```
void convertString(char *input, char *output);
```

Also within the function the terminating zero is not copied from the input string to the output string. The function simply exits.

```
if(strlen(input)== 0)
{
    return;
}
```

And it is inefficient to calculate the length of the string in each recursion. You could substitute this condition at least for

```
if ( input[0] == '\0' )
```

or

```
if ( *input == '\0' )
```

or

```
if ( !*input )
```

Also it is unclear why the function is named `convertString` instead of for example `copyString`.

Take into account that there is a common convention that string functions return pointers to strings they process.
The function can be defined simpler.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * copyString( char *output, const char *input )
{
    if ( ( *output = *input ) ) copyString( output + 1, input + 1 );
    return output;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char input[] = "abcdefg";
    char output[sizeof(input)];

    puts( copyString( output, input ) );    

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abcdefg
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue, as aleardy pointed out by [Mr. JP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31020316/2173917), is `&output` does not give you a `char **`, it gives a `char (*)[8]` in this case, which will decay into a `char *` when used as function argument.

In your case, you don't need a pointer-to-pointer to alter the contents of the memory area pointed by that pointer. A simple pointer will do. You can change

```
void convertString(char *input, char **output)
```

to

```
void convertString(char *input, char *output)  //output is of type char*
```

and other occurrences of `output` similarly and call it like

```
convertString(input, output);
```

that should work.

That said, you should null-terminate `output` to make it use as a *string*.

Comment: Are you positive that a `char(*)[8]` decays to a `char*` ? Being a pointer and not an array itself, I don't think it does.

Comment: @Quentin well, in case of a function call , I think it does, isn't it?

Comment: [Nope](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc0ddcfc8466cd66), it doesn't. Only array names decay to pointers.

Comment: @Quentin Why use a C++ compiler for compiling C code? check [this](http://rextester.com/XQNUSX24688).

Comment: My bad ! I wan't paying attention there. However, turning on warnings gives, again, `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func’ from incompatible pointer type`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void convertString(char *input, char *output)
{
    if(strlen(input)== 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    *output = *input;
    output++;
    convertString(input+1,output);
}
int main()
{
    char input[] = "abcdefg";
    char output[sizeof(input)];
    convertString(input, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

Probably this is what you wanted to do?